# Enable PHP for only a specific file instead of all files of a specific extension

Tags: php, apache

Using Apache it's easy to enable PHP for all files of any extension:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css .js .txt .xml
```

**How do I enable PHP for only a specific file but not all other files with that same extension?**

I have tried `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php test.xml` and it did not work and the search engines aren't coughing up anything remotely relevant.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do, but another option is .htaccess rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) can be used inside a [<Files>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#files) container.

> ## AddHandler Directive
>
> - Description:    Maps the filename extensions to the specified handler
> - [Context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/directive-dict.html#Context):   server config, virtual host, **directory**, .htaccess

... where `directory` stands for:

> ## directory
>
> A directive marked as being valid in this context may be used inside <Directory>, <Location>, **<Files>**, <If>,
>   and <Proxy> containers in the server configuration files,
>   subject to the restrictions outlined in Configuration Sections.

And [<Files>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#files) can be used from `.htaccess` just fine:

> ## <Files> Directive
>
> - Description:    Contains directives that apply to matched filenames
> - Context:    server config, virtual host, directory, **.htaccess**

Comment: Can you please elaborate and I presume this will work in an `.htaccess` file and not the direct server configuration?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Feel free to ask if something in the documentation is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
<Files hello.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

The file tag selects only hello.html,the AddType then adds php support for all files it can "access". Due to the Files header, it can only "access" hello.html, and so only enable php for this one.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it